# Modify microstack snap nova config

Tags: snap, openstack

I've installed the Microstack snap and was wondering how I can change the `nova.conf`.

The running snap tells me the change should be made in `$SNAP_COMMON/etc/nova.conf.d`, but first of all the config is not there and second if I create it it doesn't show up after a snap restart.

Reason of the change is I want to test with SRIOV so I need to whitelist some hardware in the `nova.conf`

Answer (score 0):

It's here:

```
/snap/microstack/current/etc/nova/nova.conf
```